# Permission error while installing vscode plugin in Travis

Tags: visual-studio-code, continuous-integration, travis-ci, vscode-extensions, permission-denied

Im testing my project in travis.
Few days ago it start to fail.
It complains about access permissions during publishing of VSCode extension.
It fails in Travis only. Locally it runs ok on Linux, MacOS and Windows. It also passes ok in appveyor
I cant find anything helpful in internet about this one.
my project is public

https://github.com/wix/stylable-intelligence

Here is log of build that fails

https://travis-ci.org/wix/stylable-intelligence/jobs/301428198

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue that was causing the problem.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25848

This hack fixed it.

```
chmod a+x /opt/vscode-1.18.0/resources/app/node_modules/vscode-ripgrep/bin/rg
```